# Как из QlineEdit дать значение элементу массива из другого .py файла?

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, qt-designer, qlineedit

У меня есть интерфейс в main.py, и файл конфигурации с переменными config.py.

main.ру:

```py
    import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from menu import Ui_MenuWindow
import config as cf


class Ui_MainWindow(object):

        def openMenu(self):
                self.window = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
                self.ui = Ui_MenuWindow()
                self.ui.setupUi(self.window)
                self.window.show()

        def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
                MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
                MainWindow.resize(800, 431)
                MainWindow.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(35, 39, 42);\n"
                                         "\n"
                                         "\n"
                                         "QLineEdit::focus {\n"
                                         "    border: 2px;\n"
                                         "}\n"
                                         "\n"
                                         "")
                self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
                self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
                self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
                self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 100, 201, 61))
                self.label_2.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(201, 51))
                font = QtGui.QFont()
                font.setFamily("Montserrat")
                font.setPointSize(14)
                font.setBold(False)
                font.setItalic(False)
                font.setWeight(10)
                self.label_2.setFont(font)
                self.label_2.setStyleSheet("font: 87 14pt \"Montserrat\";\n"
                                           "color: rgb(255, 255, 255)")
                self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
                self.widget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.centralwidget)
                self.widget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(170, 10, 481, 61))
                self.widget.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(44, 47, 51);\n"
                                          "border-radius: 10px;")
                self.widget.setObjectName("widget")
                self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.widget)
                self.label.setEnabled(True)
                self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(120, 0, 231, 61))
                self.label.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(221, 51))
                font = QtGui.QFont()
                font.setFamily("Segoe UI Black")
                font.setPointSize(22)
                font.setBold(True)
                font.setWeight(75)
                self.label.setFont(font)
                self.label.setAutoFillBackground(False)
                self.label.setStyleSheet("text-align: center;\n"
                                         "color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
                self.label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
                self.label.setObjectName("label")
                self.lineEdit_2 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
                self.lineEdit_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(410, 200, 311, 20))
                font = QtGui.QFont()
                font.setFamily("Segoe UI Light")
                self.lineEdit_2.setFont(font)
                self.lineEdit_2.setAutoFillBackground(False)
                self.lineEdit_2.setStyleSheet("    background-color: rgb(44, 47, 51);\n"
                                              "    border: 1px solid  rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
                                              "    color: white;\n"
                                              "    border-radius: 5px;")
                self.lineEdit_2.setText("")
                self.lineEdit_2.setObjectName("lineEdit_2")
                self.label_5 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
                self.label_5.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 200, 361, 21))
                font = QtGui.QFont()
                font.setFamily("Segoe UI Semibold")
                font.setPointSize(9)
                self.label_5.setFont(font)
                self.label_5.setStyleSheet("color: white;\n"
                                           "")
                self.label_5.setObjectName("label_5")
                self.label_6 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
                self.label_6.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 240, 371, 41))
                font = QtGui.QFont()
                font.setFamily("Segoe UI Semibold")
                font.setPointSize(9)
                self.label_6.setFont(font)
                self.label_6.setStyleSheet("color: white;\n"
                                           "")
                self.label_6.setObjectName("label_6")
                self.lineEdit_3 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
                self.lineEdit_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(410, 240, 311, 20))
                font = QtGui.QFont()
                font.setFamily("Segoe UI Light")
                self.lineEdit_3.setFont(font)
                self.lineEdit_3.setAutoFillBackground(False)
                self.lineEdit_3.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(44, 47, 51);\n"
                                              "border: 1px solid  rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
                                              "color: white;\n"
                                              "border-radius: 5px;")
                self.lineEdit_3.setText("")
                self.lineEdit_3.setObjectName("lineEdit_3")
                self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget, clicked=lambda: self.update_data())
                self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(310, 320, 181, 61))
                font = QtGui.QFont()
                font.setFamily("Segoe UI Black")
                font.setPointSize(18)
                font.setBold(True)
                font.setWeight(75)
                self.pushButton.setFont(font)
                self.pushButton.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
                                              "    text-align: center;\n"
                                              "    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
                                              "    background-color: rgb(44, 47, 51);\n"
                                              "    border-radius: 10px;\n"
                                              "}\n"
                                              "\n"
                                              "QPushButton:hover {\n"
                                              "    text-align: center;\n"
                                              "    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
                                              "    background-color: #404EED;\n"
                                              "    border-radius: 10px;\n"
                                              "\n"
                                              "}\n"
                                              "\n"
                                              "QPushButton::focus {\n"
                                              "    background-color:rgb(153, 170, 181);\n"
                                              "    color: rgb(44, 47, 51);\n"
                                              "}")
                self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
                self.label_4 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
                self.label_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(420, 90, 341, 61))
                font = QtGui.QFont()
                font.setFamily("Segoe UI Semibold")
                font.setBold(True)
                font.setWeight(75)
                self.label_4.setFont(font)
                self.label_4.setStyleSheet("color: rgb(206, 206, 206);\n"
                                           "")
                self.label_4.setObjectName("label_4")
                self.label_7 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
                self.label_7.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(50, 10, 81, 61))
                self.label_7.setStyleSheet("object-fit: cover;")
                self.label_7.setText("")
                self.label_7.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("icon.png"))
                self.label_7.setScaledContents(True)
                self.label_7.setWordWrap(False)
                self.label_7.setObjectName("label_7")
                MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
                self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
                self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 800, 21))
                self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
                MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
                self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
                self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
                MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

                self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
                QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

        def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
                _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
                MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
                self.label_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Setup before start"))
                self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", " Discord Toolz"))
                self.lineEdit_2.setWhatsThis(_translate("MainWindow", "<html><head/><body><p><br/></p></body></html>"))
                self.label_5.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Channel ID"))
                self.label_6.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Changes how fast the messages are posted (in seconds) \n"
                                                              " (Anything under 0.7 tends to break it (┛✧Д✧))┛彡┻━┻ )"))
                self.lineEdit_3.setWhatsThis(_translate("MainWindow", "<html><head/><body><p><br/></p></body></html>"))
                self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "START"))
                self.label_4.setText(
                        _translate("MainWindow", "We recommend creating a file that will contain your initial data \n"
                                                 "for running the script. \n"
                                                 "Copying from a file on the desktop is easier than constantly \n"
                                                 "launching the browser"))


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
        def __init__(self, parent=None):
                super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
                self.setupUi(self)

                self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.update_data)
                cf.SpamSpeed = self.lineEdit_3.text()
                cf.DiscordChannel = self.lineEdit_2.text()

        def update_data(self):
                cf.SpamSpeed = self.lineEdit_3.text()
                cf.DiscordChannel = self.lineEdit_2.text()
                openMenu()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

а вот config.py

```
# Basic Config (For all bots)
pythonCommand = "python" # If you have the python command set to something else such as python3
userToken = [] # User Tokens here. example 'token','token' | 'email:pass', 'token'
DiscordChannel = ''  # Channel ID,
SpamSpeed = 120 # Changes how fast the messages are posted. (Anything under 0.7 tends to break it (┛✧Д✧))┛彡┻━┻ )
textRandom = True # if the root has 'text.txt' it will pick a random text line and send it.
textFull = False # Will send everything written in 'text.txt'
discumLog = True # Displays Discums Logs, Very useful for providing more info on what went wrong.

#Server Joiner
useTokenJoin = True
inviteLink = '' # Only the last 6 digits of the invite link https://discord.gg/XXXXXX | Unless you are using email join then just the full URL
autojoinServer = True # Will auto join the inviteLink server if True
useBrowser = 'Firefox' # Chrome | Firefox | Edge (windows only) | Set the browser used for joining the servers.
joinSpeed = 3 # Changes how fast the bot will start the server joiner

#DM Spam
DiscordServer = '' # Server ID (https://i.imgur.com/m06TSEx.png this one)
ScanAllServers = False # (True or False) Instead of using a server ID this will scan all of the users joined servers. 
HeavyScrape = False # (True or False) Use this for servers with a lot of users

#Account Creator
captchaAPI = 'c906c780567d1abd410cdf45c9d0aee3' #2captcha API Key
mailServer = 'pop.gmail.com' # Mail server, pop 3 version. (example = "pop.mail.ru")

#Picture spam
DirPictures = 'pictures' # Picture(s) location, end directory with a double slash.
```

И, собственно, вопрос, как мне значение из LineEdit_2 в main.py засунуть значение в DiscordChannel который в config.py

Comment: Я пробовал импортировать в конфиг типа ```from main import Ui_MainWindow потом из него setupUi. но после этого когда пытаюсь импортировать var пишет ошибку типа нету в сетапУи штуки вар

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: исспользуй глобальную переменную- `global var` в вызове функции

Comment: @ganz в main.py?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы не предоставляете минимально-воспроизводимый пример, это не хорошо.

**q1386380_main.py**

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.Qt import *

import q1386380_config as cf                                                            # +++


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.resize(800, 600)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(100, 30, 600, 40))
        
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Покажите cf.var', self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(300, 160, 200, 40))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):                      
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)        

        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.update_data)      
        
        print(f'1 cf.var[0] = {cf.var[0]}') 
        cf.var[0] = self.lineEdit.text()
        print(f'2 cf.var[0] = {cf.var[0]}')

    def update_data(self):
        cf.var[0] = self.lineEdit.text()
        print(f'3 cf.var[0] = {cf.var[0]}')
        
        
        
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**q1386380_config.py**

var = [None, ]                 # +++ None

---

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: @ТимофейШулимов что не так?

Comment: всё отлично, только не могу понять как встроить это в мой код

Comment: @ТимофейШулимов, если мой ответ помог вам, то не забудьте пометить как правильный, если вы не знаете, как это сделать, проверьте https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour . Если у вас есть другие проблемы - опубликуйте новый вопрос.

Comment: я изменил вопрос, добавил полные коды файлов, ели вам не сложно, не могли бы вы описать решение но уже с моими названиями переменных?

Comment: @ТимофейШулимов, пожалуйста, прочитайте внимательно мой предыдущий комментарий.